# Vue-Plyr loading video very slow

Tags: vue.js, iframe, vuejs3, plyr.js, vue-plyr

My video's size is `2.7 MB` and `vue-plyr` needs 10 seconds or so to load it in my local development environment (`laravel/vue`). During that time the `plyr` frame just stays black. The bad thing is that it doesn't even `autoplay` after it's loaded.

Am I doing something wrong or is this behaviour normal?

This is how I set it up:

```
<template>
  <section id="vision" class="vision">
    <vue-plyr>
      <video
        controls
        crossorigin
        playsinline
        muted
        loop
        autoplay
      >
        <source
          size="1080"
          src="videos/cgi_neutral.mp4"
          type="video/mp4"
        />
      </video>
    </vue-plyr>
  </section>
</template>
```

Comment: Any news? It works well for me on desktop too but mobile won't play the video, loading forever...